# How call router navigate method instead of routerLink?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, angular-routing, angular-router

I am trying to replace a routerLink with the router's navigate method. Unfortunately it doesn't work and I can no longer explain it. The routerLink works without any problems.

I want to replace this:

```
<mat-list-item role="listitem" [routerLink]="['details', 2]" routerLinkActive="active">
```

With this:

```
<mat-list-item role="listitem" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="openDetails(2)">
```

And this is how I use the navigate method:

```
openDetails(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['details', id]);
}
```

My router config looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MasterComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'details/:id',
        component: DetailsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pass in the navigation extras object to the navigate method with the relativeTo field set to the current route like this:

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }

this.router.navigate(['details', id], {relativeTo:this.route});
```

Comment: Ok, now it works. But how can I set the route to active now? What can I use instead of the routerLinkActive directive in the template?